# Was the interview with the Norwegian prime minister real?

Tags: trolljegeren

At the end of the movie [Trolljegeren](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1740707/combined) (Trollhunter) they include [some footage with the Norwegian prime minister](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jBuNMHzqmI) talking about trolls. Is that new text that is dubbed over the scene, or did he really say that?

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but my guess is that it's dubbed. The camera pans from Stoltenberg to another man, so his face is off screen and we cannot check his lips. Either ways, the other man's reaction looks genuine and is priceless!

Comment: Nice video you found of this. Thanks for inclusion.

Comment: Link to the press conference: http://media01.smartcom.no/Microsite/dss_01.aspx?eventid=5321 The outtake used in the movie starts at about 41:30.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a Norwegian citizen I can confirm that this clip is real and that all the text was from the actual press footage. Our prime minister was talking about some power lines that caused a **big** debate here in Norway.  The producers of the movie saw this press footage and thought it would go perfect with the movie, so they asked our prime minister if they could use it.

The man on the right was not part of the real footage, though.

Comment: Cool. Can you add some reference?

Comment: Ofcourse, but its in Norwegian: http://p3.no/filmpolitiet/2011/12/troll-karet-til-beste-filmmonster/

Comment: I learned the wrong languages so far. :-) In the article also is David Cameron mentioned with the movie "Attack the block". I didn't saw Cameron in the movie (but I could've missed it), what is said there about this?

Comment: Its a full paragraf talking about the "cameo" of the prime minister. Its about using the pressconferanse as a cameo.
I saw the pressconferance live myself, and I must say, its a clever use of a somewhat dry primeminister talking about the powerlines nobody wanted to have.

Answer (score 5):

It’s not fake, but slightly edited. (Well, one thing is fake. The head of the TST official was superimposed upon whoever sat next to Stoltenberg.) But Stoltenberg actually said that we have Troll. But Troll is the name of an gas field in the Northern Sea, in which there are three oil platforms, Troll A, Troll B and Troll C. (In Norwegian, the word troll is both singular and plural.)